# Windows 7.0 User Rights problem when moving a folder to c:\inetpub\wwwroot

Tags: security, windows-7

I tried to *Move* a published version of my ASP.NET application to Windows 7.0 into:

`C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\`

I am prevented from doing this because I don't have the correct rights (admin rights).

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

change the permissions. Open powershell as admin and write this:

```
icacls c:\InetPub\wwwroot /grant "YourUserName:(OI)(CI)F"
```

Comment: No i resolved the issue. Folder which i am trying to move has Read Only Property, I unchecked the property !!

Comment: @Chok Post it as a self answer, then.